# how to fix 'creates a temporary which is freed while still in use'?

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and trying to implement a cache-like struct to cache an object, but I'm stuck on an error.

**src/main.rs**

```rust
// The Result object to be cached
struct Result {
    value: u32,
}

struct Cacher<'a, T>
where
    T: Fn(u32) -> u32,
{
    calc: T,
    value: Option<&'a Result>,
}

impl<'a, T> Cacher<'a, T>
where
    T: Fn(u32) -> u32,
{
    fn new(calc: T) -> Cacher<'a, T> {
        Cacher { calc, value: None }
    }

    fn get_value(&mut self, arg: u32) -> &Result {
        match self.value {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => {
                let v = (self.calc)(arg);
                self.value = Some(&Result { value: v });
                self.value.unwrap()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:28:40
   |
15 |     impl<'a, T> Cacher<'a, T>
   |          -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
28 |                     self.value = Some(&Result { value: v });
   |                     -------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                     |                  |
   |                     |                  creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
   |                     assignment requires that borrow lasts for `'a`
```

How would one fix this?

Comment: [Use `Option<Result>` and drop the `&`.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4bb7ba471a2d2ff1073329b71686c4f2) Since `Cacher` needs to come up with the result and store it for future invocations, it needs to own it. A reference can refer to the data that someone else owns, and there is no one else to own `Result`. (This is the kind of code that C or C++ would happily allow you to write, and which would result in a crash because you'd return a reference to a local.)

Comment: @user4815162342 could you please show me the fixed version? the way you mentioned i've already tried but failed.

Comment: The updated comment contains a link to the playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return a reference to a value if no one owns this value.
Also when you are using your `Cacher` you need to ensure that reference you've got by `get_value` will not outlive `Cacher` itself.

```
// The Result object to be cached
struct Result {
    value: u32,
}

struct Cacher<T>
where
    T: Fn(u32) -> u32,
{
    calc: T,
    value: Option<Result>, // We need to own the Result
}

impl<T> Cacher<T>
where
    T: Fn(u32) -> u32,
{
    fn new(calc: T) -> Cacher<T> {
        Cacher { calc, value: None }
    }

    fn get_value(&mut self, arg: u32) -> &Result {
        match self.value {
            Some(ref v) => v, // destructuring value by reference to it
            None => {
                let v = (self.calc)(arg);
                self.value = Some(Result { value: v });
                self.value.as_ref().unwrap() // unwrapping value by reference to it
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. Of course I meant destructuring.